# Can jQuery alter image path before image loads?

Tags: jquery, image, responsive-design

I'm building a web site that will run locally on a tablet that client is giving to new business prospects. Because of this, I can't use any PHP. The design being what it is necessitates that I swap out some images depending on whether the tablet orientation is portrait or landscape. Just to be clear I need to swap images; they cannot simply resize.

I've written the following HTML:

```
<img src="img/derp/2.jpg"/>
```

and jQuery:

```
//DETECT THE INITIAL SCREEN WIDTH AND CHANGE THE PATH TO LOAD THE APPROPRIATE IMAGES

    if ($(window).width() < 960) {
        $("img").each(function() {
            $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("src").replace("img/derp", "img/port"));
        });
    }

    else {
        $("img").each(function() {
              $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("src").replace("img/derp", "img/land"));
        });

    }


//DETECT THE CHANGED SCREEN WIDTH AND SWITCH THE IMAGE PATH IF NECESSARY

$(window).on('resize', function() {

        if ($(window).width() < 960) {
            $("img").each(function() {
                  $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("src").replace("img/land", "img/port"));
            });

        } else {
            $("img").each(function() {
                  $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("src").replace("img/port", "img/land"));
            });
        }
});
```

This all works well, except that it initially throws a 404 in the console before switching to the proper image directory. I've tried loading this script in the  as well as at the top of the HTML, but it makes no difference.

Does anyone know of a way I can get the jQuery to alter the image path BEFORE the browser attempts to load the image so it doesn't give me a 404?

Answer (score 1):

The wheel has already been invented.

**CSS3**

```
<img src="image.jpg"
 data-src-600px="image-600px.jpg"
 data-src-800px="image-800px.jpg"
 alt="">
```

See more: http://css-tricks.com/techniques-for-context-specific-images/

Comment: I like this in theory, but I can't get it to work in any browser. I read the linked article and the article linked in that article, etc. Just can't get it to work :(

Answer (score 0):

A much easier solution is to use media queries instead of substituting images with jQuery. Set an image as a background through CSS and apply different rules based on the screen size. It will work faster and there will be no "blinking"/page redrawing when one image is replaced with another.

Comment: I considered that, but this is for gallery images. There are about 24 of them that will need to change. The rest will resize proportionately. Wouldn't I have to write a separate class for each one or is there a way with CSS to change the path instead of changing the background image?

Comment: If the images are the same every time, I would use a sprite, which will give you a major performance boost. If they constantly change, you are better off with a JavaScript solution.

Comment: Unfortunately, they're not the same. It's a gallery of photos. Most are square and size proportionately, but some are long rectangles that resize to different proportions and thus have to be swapped. Thanks for the help though!